# Uploading photos to Facebook: Adding parameters before executing the newUploadPhotoRequest call gives the 'OAuthException' error

Tags: android, facebook, photos

Summary: Trying to post an image, and description on Facebook. If the image URL is null, I use a local drawable default image to upload to photos.

To upload the local image, I am using the following code:

My code:

```
Request.Callback uploadPhotoRequestCallback = new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        if (response.getError() != null) { 
            //post error
        } else{
            String uploadResponse = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("id");
            if (uploadResponse is valid) { 
                  parameters.putString("message", description);
            } else { 
                  //error
            } 
        }
    }
};

Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), R.drawable.default_image), uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

This executes with the following:

```
{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 324, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#324) Requires upload file}
```

Notes:
1. The image uploads successfully without
        `request.setParameters(parameters);`
2. Tried `parameters.putString("name", description);` instead of
    `parameters.putString("message", description);`

Why is adding parameters causing an OAuthException?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create an newUploadPhotoRequest, that method will implicitly add some parameters to the Request object that's returned. When you call setParameter, you're replacing those implicit parameters with your own, which causes the request to be missing some required params.

What you should do instead is:

```
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), R.drawable.default_image), uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); // <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT
parameters.putString(...);
// add more params here
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: @MingLi is it possible that I can add location to the uploaded photo?

Comment: add some text by using above: parameters.putString("message", description); 
and it perfectly worked :)

Comment: How can i add link with image