# Unable to post an image from drawable to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to pass an image from the drawables folder to the feed dialogue. But I am unable to view the image in facebook feed dialogue. Rest of the parameters are available. I am using facebook SDK 3.5. Here is the function for showing feed dialog.

```
 private void publishFeedDialog() {


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putByteArray("picture", bitMapData);
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        //params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");


        WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Error posting story", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Publish feed will work only with **url** to image.

See `picture` property under feed documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

If you want to publish image from your memory (like drawable folder) then you need to use: `Request.newUploadPhotoRequest()`

Beside this, you can use this simple open source library that supports SDK 3.5 for doing actions like publish photo, feed and so on in a very simple way: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

#### UPDATE

**Option 1**
You can use `Request.newUploadPhotoRequest()`, but this method doesn't allow you to add any additional property except the image itself.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), bitmap , new Request.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response)
    {
        // ... handle the response...           
    }
});
```

**Option 2**
If you want to add additional properties to the image like description, then do almost the same but with raw graph api call. The facebook implementation of `Request.newUploadPhotoRequest()` does exactly the same but without setting additional properties.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putParcelable("picture", bitmap);
params.putString("message", "This is the description of the image");
params.putString("place", "1235456498726"); // place id of the image

Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", bundle, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback()
{
    @Override    
    public void onCompleted(Response response)
    {
        // ... handle the response...
    }
});

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Comment: Can you check the answer in this link and let me know you meant something like that?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917929/uploading-photos-to-facebook-adding-parameters-before-executing-the-newuploadph

Comment: Correct, the answer of @Ming Li is the right solution for you

Comment: @srumku: Thanks, let me check the solution and let you know the details.

Comment: @srumku: It will be a great help if you can update your answer with missing code integrated in to my code. I am bit confused how to include the answer in that link to my code.

Comment: @sromku Hey i have same issue of sharing image on Facebook. I tried with your solution option2 but its not sharing image on facebook. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: @GrIsHu have you added all needed permissions and `onResume()` and `onActivityResult()` methods like it shown [here](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#usage)?

Comment: I am not using facebook sdk 3.5. I am using facebook sdk 3.0.2 so in that sdk there is not class called `SimpleFacebook`.

Comment: @GrIsHu the class `SimpleFacebook` comes not from original facebook sdk but from the [library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook). the library just wraps the original sdk and gives you more convenient api

Comment: I tired your second option but its not working even no error,I'm using SDK 3.6