# Java convert drawable to bytearray

Tags: java, android, facebook, bitmap

I was having some problem when trying to customize the share dialog of Facebook in Android. Basically what I am trying to do is get the drawable image from ImageView component then pass it as params into my share dialog. Here is the codes where I set image to my ImageView:

```
ivEventDtl.setImageDrawable(EventDrawableImage.resizeEventDetailImage(
            eventModel.getEventPic(), context));
```

This one was done in onCreate(). the eventModel.getEventPic() was a string. Then when my facebook button on click, I am executing this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void postToWall() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();  
    params.putString("name", txtEventDtlName.getText().toString());
    params.putString("caption", "Date: " + txtEventDtlDate.getText().toString());
    params.putString("link", "");
    params.putString("description", txtEventDtlDesc.getText().toString());
    //params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");
    try {
        params.putByteArray("picture", EventDrawableImage.extractBytes(ivEventDtl.getDrawable()));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    facebook.dialog(getActivity(), "feed", params, new DialogListener() {

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

And the method to convert drawable to byte array:

```
public static byte[] extractBytes(Drawable image) throws IOException {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
    return bitmapdata;
}
```

It was working fine if I hardcode the picture with the URL. When I changed it to the convert drawable to byte array one, all the params in share dialog does not show. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I modified the codes to take in the picture string and resize to larger than 200x200 then convert it into bitmap before passing it as params:

```
Drawable image = EventDrawableImage.resizeShareDialogueImage(eventPicPath, context);
Bitmap bitmap = EventDrawableImage.drawableToBitmap(image);

public static Drawable resizeShareDialogueImage(String eventPic,
        Context context) {
    String uri = "@drawable/" + eventPic;
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
            context.getPackageName());
    Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) res).getBitmap();
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 250, 250, true));
    return d;
}

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

public void postToWall() {
    Drawable image = EventDrawableImage.resizeShareDialogueImage(eventPicPath, context);

    Bitmap bitmap = EventDrawableImage.drawableToBitmap(image);

    final Bundle params = new Bundle();  
    params.putString("name", txtEventDtlName.getText().toString());
    params.putString("caption", "Date: " + txtEventDtlDate.getText().toString());
    params.putString("link", "");
    params.putString("description", txtEventDtlDesc.getText().toString());
    params.putParcelable("picture", bitmap);
    //params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            facebook.dialog(getActivity(), "feed", params, new DialogListener() {

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                }

                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                }

                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                }

                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });
        }
    });

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: what you tried before that was working??

Comment: If I used the commented out that URL for picture, it was working. I not sure if it's the picture in byte array causing the share dialogue does not take in parameters, or my convert method got problem. There is no error message though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant pass an image bitmap directly in the params, you must pass a URI. The URI must point a resource the facebook app can access. You can quickly get a URI from a bitmap like this:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "temp", "Test Image");
params.putString("picture", path);
```

Use that instead of setting picture directly to bitmap or bitmap bytes.

Comment: Nope, does not work. If I put back the byte array image, all my other params are missing from share dialogue as well

Comment: Well a quick google search shows you cannot pass image bytes to this function. You must pass a URI. You need to save bytes to file and pass URI to that file. Here is all the detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145375/unable-to-post-an-image-from-drawable-to-facebook

Comment: But what should I do with that? I am confused that he didnt do anything with the bitmap :(

Comment: Can you help me take a look at the edited portion? I changed it but still, the image is breaking all my other params

Comment: You cant put a bitmap in the params. You have to save the bitmap to a file, and in the params, put the file path.

Comment: No you are still sticking the bitmap into the params. You can't do that.

Comment: But I thought that's what he does from the link you provided

Comment: Sorry that link i posted is using the uploadphotorequest which is fir uploading photos. It is different. I will uodate my answer.... One sec

Comment: Okay sure thanks a lot. I guess I will just grab some images online and use it as URI :) Thanks for the helps !!

Comment: You cant use the code I posted to post your drawable?

Answer (score 0):

The feed dialog does not support binary data for the "picture" parameter. It must be an internet addressable URL (i.e. not a local file).

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2 for more info.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! I guess I have to use internet addressable URL then :(